# SQL joining two tables with common row

Tags: sql, sybase

I have 2 tables in sybase

**Account_table**

```
Id     account_code
1      A
2      B
3      C
```

**Associate_table**

```
id     account_code
1      A
1      B
1      C
2      A
2      B
3      A
3      C
```

I have this sql query

```
SELECT * FROM account_table account, associate_table assoc
WHERE account.account_code = assoc.account_code
```

This query will return 7 rows. What I want is to return the rows from associate_table that is only common to the 3 accounts like this:

```
account id     account_code      Assoc Id
    1                A              1
    2                B              1
    3                C              1
```

Can anyone help what kind of join should I do?

Comment: Strange logic in your result set, can you explain a bit farther why the query would return `assoc id` with `1`?

Comment: In the account table, we have 3 account codes, A,B and C. In assoc table, we have multiple entries of account code, but the id 1 is the only common for all three. If we have another entry in assoc table containing id=2 account_code=C, we will have 3 more rows in the result.

Comment: OK, now I understand the concept, I've posted my version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT b.id account_id,a.code account_code,a.id assoc_id
 FROM  associate a, 
       account b 
WHERE  a.code = b.code 
  AND  a.id IN (SELECT a.id 
                    FROM   associate a, 
                           account b 
                    WHERE  a.code = b.code 
                    GROUP  BY a.id 
                    HAVING Count(*) = (SELECT Count(*) 
                                       FROM   account));
```

NOTE: this query works only if you have unique values in Id and account_code columns in account table. And also, your associate_table should contain unique combination of (id, account,code). i.e., associate table should not contain (1,A) or any pair twice.

Comment: It works. Thanks. But can I ask you what is the purpose of the "HAVING" part of the query

Comment: HAVING clause is used whenever you need to compare with group function .

Comment: What I mean is can it be more simple? For example, if I have a complicated where conditions in the upper part of the query, I would have to repeat these conditions on the select count(*) on the having part of the query, which makes the query more complicated. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: The query could be simplified but count(*) is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT AC.ID,AC.account_code,ASS.ID 
FROM account_table AC INNER JOIN associate_table AS ASS ON AC.account_code = ASS.account_code
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that we use Sybase. It doesn't seem to work there.

Answer (score 0):

OK so far answer is accepted I'll post simpler one:

```
SELECT *
FROM account_table   AS account,
     associate_table AS assoc
WHERE account.account_code  = assoc.account_code 
HAVING (
        SELECT
          COUNT(*)
        FROM associate_table assoc_2
        WHERE assoc_2.id = assoc.id
    ) = 3
```

here `3` is the number of codes `account` table has, if it's gonna be dynamic (changing over time),

you can use `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM account_table)` instead of exact number. Also I'm sure it will be cached by database engine, so requires less resources